# How to implement infinite scroll in react js with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having api with query of page number and count. When i render the component i need to display only 4 results per page. If i scroll to bottom next set of records will get append. It will run till the end. I already tried to implement this one. Please check my below code. This code is not working properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    scrollToload(pageNo, count) {
      $.ajax({
        url:url+'pageNo='+pageNo+'&count='+count,
        type:'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data) {
          this.setState({
            result:data
          });
        }.bind(this)
      });
    }
    handleScroll () {
      var self = this;
      var count = 0, pageNo = 0;
      var lastScrollTop = 0;
      var $scrollDiv = $('.scroll-content');
      $scrollDiv.on('scroll', function(){
        var contentHeight = $('.scroll-content > div').innerHeight()-40;
        var windowHeight = $scrollDiv.innerHeight();
        var scrollTop = $scrollDiv.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop > (contentHeight-windowHeight)) {
          if(!self.state.loadingFlag) {
            $('#preloader').show();
            count += 4;
            page += 1;
            self.setState({
              loadingFlag:true
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
              self.scrollToload(pageNo, count);
            }, 10);
          }
          lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        }
      });
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      this.handleScroll ()
    }
render() {
  return <div className="scroll-content">
   {this.state.map(function(el, i){
     return <div key={i}>
       <img src={el.url} />
       <h2>{el.title}</h2>
     </div>
   })}
</div>
}
}
```

export default App;
 Right now it working better in browsers sometimes but mobile not working properly. Is any other better way to improve this concept?

Comment: Why did you add a Reactjs tag? I don't see any use of React whatsoever. This is jQuery

Comment: I put here only the functions where i used inside of the react component @DenisMysenko

Comment: Just as a point, always include what specifically went wrong, not just "it doesn't work". Is it not loading new pages at all? Loading them, but slowly? Loading wrong pages? Getting console errors? etc.

Comment: I think you're misusing react. half the point of react is to rely on vdom for drawing. the direct manipulation of dom using jquery from componentDidMount begs the question why you use react.

Comment: I'd suggest not re-inventing the wheel here and just using something like https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite

Comment: I have updated my question @MartinAlgesten

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jack. How we can stop scroll event if has no more data. I can't control this